# kubectl set image deployment doesn't set new container image (gcp)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci

```
kubectl set image deployment/$DEPLOYMENT_EXTENSION $INSTANCE_NAME=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$DOCKER_REPOSITORY:latest
```

I use this command do load new created image to my existing cluster (update version of my app) . But when I do it , and then go to the site , I don't see any changes .

```
spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      containers:
      - name: booknotes
        image: gcr.io/my-image:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

I've also added this 2 lines in deployment.yaml file and applied it for my cluser:

```
imagePullPolicy: Always
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

But it still doesn't work. Can it be because I use `:latest` tag ? Or it isn't related ? If you have some idias pls let me know. And also if you need additional info , I will attach it !

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
   stages:
      - build
      - docker-push
      - deploy

    cache:
      paths:
        - node_modules/

    build:
      stage: build
      image: node:latest
      script:
        - yarn install
        - npm run build
      artifacts:
        paths:
          - dist/
      only:
        - master

    docker:
      stage: docker-push
      image: docker:18.09.7

      services:
        - docker:18.09.7-dind
        - google/cloud-sdk:latest

      script:
        - echo $GCP_ACCESS_JSON > $CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
        - cat $CI_PIPELINE_ID.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin $GCP_REGION
        - docker build -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$DOCKER_REPOSITORY:latest .
        - docker push gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$DOCKER_REPOSITORY:latest

      only:
        - master

    test:
      stage: deploy
      image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
      script:
        - echo $GCP_ACCESS_JSON > $CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
        - gcloud auth activate-service-account $GCP_CE_PROJECT_EMAIL --key-file $CI_PIPELINE_ID.json --project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
        - gcloud container clusters get-credentials $CLUSTER_NAME --zone $ZONE --project $PROJECT_NAME
        - kubectl set image deployment/$DEPLOYMENT_EXTENSION $INSTANCE_NAME=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$DOCKER_REPOSITORY:latest

      only:
        - master
```

Answer (score 2):

This question, the symptoms and the reasons are very close to [this one],([Google cloud platform creating a pipeline with Kubernetes and replacing the same container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531740/google-cloud-platform-creating-a-pipeline-with-kubernetes-and-replacing-the-same/58543316#58543316))

Apply the same solution in your Gitlab-CI pipeline (use global variable to change the image tag and to deploy everytime a new one to force Kubernetes to pull and to deploy it).

I can help you on Gitlib-CI if you have difficulties to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for duplicate, I haven't found this answer by myself. I will change :latest tag to :$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME-$CI_PIPELINE_ID. This variables are global for runners and available for me. Let me know pls is it the right solution in my case?

Comment: The aim is to change the value of the image tag on each new version/build. Here it's the case. It will work

Comment: Yes, It is working ) Thanks for your response)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the latest tag will not trigger a re-deployment of your pod. Instead you could set the image and then scale the deployment.

```
kubectl set image deployment/alpine alpine=alpine:latest
kubectl scale deployment --replicas=0
kubectl scale deployment --replicas=1
```

Another option would be to set the image and then patch an annotation or change  some yaml field.